# Declare Data type that has the word order

Tags: vba

I'm having an issue declaring my data type because the word "order" is in the name. What I'd like to do is declare "Original Order Bulk Status" As a Boolean Data type, but I'm getting an error message saying "expected end of statement"
 Any ideas on how to fix this?

I'm trying to get this data type as a page field for a pivot table so right now for the dim I have:

```
Dim Original Order Bulk Status As Boolean
```

Then:

`PivotFields("Original Order Bulk Status").Orientation:=xlPageField`

Basically I just need to declare the data type for this because I was getting the error saying

> Run time error 1004: "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the `PivotTable` class"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Variable names can't contain spaces

Comment: Building on Tim's reply: Usually _underscores_ are used to replace spaces, if you really feel you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names can't contain spaces.  You could use

```
Dim Original_Order_Bulk_Status As Boolean
```

or

```
Dim OriginalOrderBulkStatus As Boolean
```

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to all of this! I'm still getting the run time error 1004 message. The rest of my code for the pivot table is

.PivotFields("Original Order Bulk Status").Orientation = xlRowField
 .PivotFields("Return Reason Code").Orientation = xlPageField
 .PivotFields("Original Order Inventory Warehouse").Orientation=xlPageField
 .PivotFields("Lines").Orientation = xlDataField

I'm having no issues with the one titles "Original Order Inventory Warehouse" because those are locations, but it's just the bulk status one and  I tried declaring it without the spaces.. Any suggestions?

Comment: On the variable declaration, or on some other line? It would help to post more of your code in the question.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q4PIrQuUyCZeZP5kSexxQ3XMp2K7lmOsaB-8EnMLVLg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry about that. It's the line :

.PivotFields("Original Order Bulk Status").Orientation:=xlPageField

Comment: I seem to have gotten it to work.

.PivotFields("Original Order " & Chr(10)  & "Bulk Status").Orientation = xlPageField 

Instead of

.PivotFields("Original Order Bulk Status").Orientation= xlPageField